# xuggle jar file not working as a dependent jar

Tags: java, eclipse, xuggler, xuggle

I read about [xuggle](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler) library
I am trying to let xuggle library work as a single jar file without any external use of any dll files or environmental variables
I read all errors that was in installing xuggler and tried all and the same exception is still shown

> Could not load library: xuggle-xuggler; version: 5;

I also tried using xuggler in maven and also same error

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.boofcv</groupId>
    <artifactId>xuggler</artifactId>
    <version>0.16</version>
</dependency>
```

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no xuggle-xuggler in
>   java.library.path

Some questions and answers i followed and no result found

[ERROR com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibraryLoader - Could not load library: xuggle-xuggler; version: 3;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18077307/error-com-xuggle-ferry-jnilibraryloader-could-not-load-library-xuggle-xuggler)
[Xuggle and java library path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076952/xuggle-and-java-library-path)
[How do I have to install/configure Xuggle to not get an UnsatisfiedLinkError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324478/how-do-i-have-to-install-configure-xuggle-to-not-get-an-unsatisfiedlinkerror)
[Could not load library: xuggle; version: 5; Using POM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21317192/could-not-load-library-xuggle-version-5-using-pom)

Answer (score 0):

On the [xuggler downloads page](http://www.xuggle.com/downloads), it talks about the current version being 5.2 (though reading elsewhere leads me to believe 5.4 is out as well). Your dependency is asking for version 0.16, with a different groud and artifact ID.

```
 <dependency>
   <groupId>xuggle</groupId>
   <artifactId>xuggle-xuggler</artifactId>
   <version>5.2</version>
  </dependency>
```

Are you sure you have the correct dependency? Have you added the xuggler repository as well?

```
<repository>
   <id>xuggle repo</id>
   <url>http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/</url>
  </repository>
```

Edit: This library has been deprecated. See [github](https://github.com/artclarke/xuggle-xuggler).

Comment: adding your dependency in my pom will lead to syntax error : Missing artifact xuggle:xuggle-xuggler:jar:5.2

Comment: Have you added the repository as well? xuggle isn't hosted on mavens servers.  Adding it to my answer.

Comment: So it looks like [the xuggle library has been deprecated](https://github.com/artclarke/xuggle-xuggler/blob/master/README) as of two years ago. The author reccommends using Humble Video.

Comment: i tried humble library i think same problem 
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no humblevideo in java.library.path